# Streams and channels in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I wanted to know how streams work internally in c#. Does StreamReader and StreamWriter use `recv()` and `send()` functions of Winsock internally. I also wanted to know the difference between streams and channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused.  A `StreamReader` is not a `Stream`, nor is a `StreamWriter`.  `Stream` doesn't know anything about network I/O as it's abstracted further out.

`NetworkStream` is a stream that knows how to talk on a network, but `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` work with abstract `Stream` references (or rather more abstract).

`NetworkStream` uses a `Socket` class, which underneath everything else does in fact call Winsock API's, but you don't really need to know anything about that to use it.

There's nothing called a "channel", perhaps you could be more specific.

Comment: And Socket is more likely to use ReadFile/WriteFile as these allow the use of asynchronous operations and IO Completion ports -- which underly all of .NET's async-IO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet they don't use winsock internally, because streams aren't only used for network IO - they're used for lots of things (moving chunks of memory, loading files, etc)

**Edit** - i've never heard of a c# channel, and google doesn't bring anything up?

Answer (score 0):

Channels are referenced throughout the Windows Communication Foundation (available in .NET 3.0).

Streams and channels are not directly related.   You should reference Windows Communication Foundation [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) found on MSDN.

Another great resource is Indigo Girl and gang at [IDesign.NET](http://www.idesign.net).

Don't forget security. [WCFSecurity](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/)